# single newline interpreted twice

Tags: curl, google-docs, google-docs-api

The issue I am referring to is nicely explained [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-documents-list-api/U0brZRckJnI).

To reiterate, using the google docs api, I can read a file in several formats using the following curl command

`curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=$fileID&exportFormat=txt"`

The issue is that each newline that is present in the google docs file is interpreted as two newlines.

This is problematic because when I update the local copy of the file and upload it back to google docs, the result is that for every newline is seen as two newlines. As you can imagine, this gets out of hand quickly.

How can I address this issue?

I can't simply replace every "\n\n" with "\n" as there may be some cases where a user might want several newlines together.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a small bash script that fixes this issue.

If anyone else comes across this issue, here is my (working?) script that maybe of some use.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/suhussai/GoogleDocApiScript/master/lineFixer.sh